# Would Torah consider kundalini awakening as Avoda Zara or is there a kosher equivilant that can be found in Jewish mysticism also?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, avodah-zarah, practical-kabbalah

BH

Is [kundalini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kundalini) awakening considered Avoda Zara or is there a kosher equivalent that can be found in Jewish mysticism also?

Comment: From what I read in your WP link, kundalini awakening is invoked mostly by forms of meditation. Is that the root of your question, may one meditate to cause kundalini awakening? Or are you referring to believing in the entire "snake" philosophy?

Comment: It's from Hinduism which is a polytheistic pagan religion

Comment: I don't know of anything similar to kundalini. However, "breathing chedvah" may be interesting to you. It's related to but not a practice of Kabbalah.  https://inner.org/meditate/jewish-breathing-meditation.php